# Store optional Image and required text in Database with PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I want to store data (mostly text) and an optional image using PDO.
So, text is no problem at all but my problem comes with the "optional" image.

How can i build a query that provides an optional image field.

for text: Something like:

```
$conn = new PDO(DNS, username, password);
$sql = "INSERT INTO DATABASE (fields) VALUES ( using place holders (? or :holder))";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindparam(':holder', '$_GET['value']');
$stmt->execute();
```

But for an optional image how can I do it?

I have the form built with the file type input:

```
<input type="file" name="image" />
```

UPDATE:

Let's imagine the following form:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="text" name="sometext" />
<input type="file" name="someimage"/>
<input type="submit" name="sendform" value="send"/>
</form>
```

The file type input is optional, what I want to know is how to build a query for that purpose using PDO, in order words the user may or not send an image but text will be required.

Thank you.

Comment: There is absolutely no use for storing images in database. There are plenty of answers on Stackoverflow explaining why it is so, you may wish to consult them to see the reasons explained.

Comment: What you mean by that, databases are for storing data is not right to store images in a db? Can you point such an answer? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

From [PHP: Large Objects (LOBs)](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php)

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('odbc:SAMPLE', 'db2inst1', 'ibmdb2');
$stmt = $db->prepare("insert into images (id, contenttype, imagedata) values (?, ?, ?)");
$id = get_new_id(); // some function to allocate a new ID

// assume that we are running as part of a file upload form
// You can find more information in the PHP documentation

$fp = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'rb');

$stmt->bindParam(1, $id);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $_FILES['file']['type']);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $fp, PDO::PARAM_LOB);

$db->beginTransaction();
$stmt->execute();
$db->commit();
```

The gist of it is that you can pass `PDOStatement::bindParam` a filehandle, tell PDO is should be saved as a Large Object (exact datatype will depend on your database), and PDO will handle the rest.

As for having the file upload be optional - just check if they uploaded anything. If they didn't, bind `null` instead of a filehandle.